# Tcl regexp matches strings that are all lower case

Tags: regex, tcl

I am using regexp to ensure the string is all lower case,but it seems not useful.

Here's my code

```
set name aAaaaA
if { [regexp {/^[a-z]$g} $name] } {
   puts "continue"
} else {
   puts "String is not lowercase. Please enter again"
}
```

I need to ensure the input is all lowercase ,and without any uppercase,symbol

And I've found `[regexp (?=.*[\L]) $name]` can express characters other than lowercase letters,but it's not useful,too.

Can anyone help for this? Thanks!

Comment: The g after the `$` means that RE won't ever match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
set name aAaaaA
if { [regexp {^[[:lower:]]+$} $name] } {
   puts "continue"
} else {
   puts "String is not lowercase. Please enter again"
}
```

See the [Tcl demo](https://ideone.com/bOTc3S).

If an empty string is valid, replace `+` with `*`.

*More details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[[:lower:]]+` - one or more lowercase letters
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to use `regexp` for this. Tcl has a command to check if a string matches some predefined character class. Lowercase is one of the predefined classes:

```
set name aAaaaA
if {[string is lower $name]} {
   puts "continue"
} else {
   puts "String is not lowercase. Please enter again"
}
```

You can add the `-strict` option if you don't want to accept the empty string: `string is lower -strict $name`

Answer (score 1):

I'd check whether any of the bad characters (upper case) are present:

```
if {[regexp {[[:upper:]]} $name]} {
    puts "String is not lowercase. Please enter again"
} else {
    puts "continue"
}
```

A good trick with regular expressions is that it is often easier to look for the inverse of what you're really after; instead of looking to see if the string is good, look to see if it is bad.